# Method 'Get' in type 'ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient' ... does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

We are using "ServiceStack" to read data from Rest service. 
Sample code:

```
string uri = "xxxxx"; (initialize uri with key)
var jsonClient = new JsonServiceClient(uri);
var obj = jconClient.Get<T>("@\r\n");
```

Above code is working fine in local machine, but not after deployment.
Error: Method 'Get' in type 'ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient' from assembly 'ServiceStack' version 4.0.40.0  ... does not have an implementation.

Any help please!

Thanks in advance,
Phani

Comment: What is the T type in this case and in your case (after looking at the definition for Get) it seems like @"\r\n" is taken as an URL.
Can you try var obj = jsonClient.Get<T>(uri); and see if it works?

Comment: @JureBogataj, even var jsonClient = new JsonServiceClient()  throwing same error.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually an indication that you're mixing dirty dlls with different versions together. Try uninstalling all NuGet packages, delete the NuGet `/packages` folder than installing all NuGet packages again and check that the `/packages` folder is only using the same version of ServiceStack for all its NuGet packages.

Comment: Thank you mythz. I tried uninstalling and installing ServiceStack libraries from nugget. But, still same problem.

Comment: @PhaniKrishnaV make sure you clear your NuGet cache as well. Process described here -> https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet#redownloading-myget-packages